# How to create a column with DDM output

Tags: qgis, shapefile, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to add a column in my point shapefile that lists points as *degrees, minutes*, not *degrees decimal*.

If it matters, I'm using 2.18.  The closest I've gotten is `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`

Comment: Is *degrees, minutes* (minutes as decimal) the format you are trying to get? Then please try `floor($x) || 'degree' || round ($x – floor($x)) * 60, 3) || 'minutes'`. ...same applies to `$y`.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito.  That's exactly what I needed.  If you'll post as an answer I'll accept it.  Though it looks like you have an extra ')' after the second 'floor($x)'

Comment: Thanks @Ben Will you post the outcome of your case as answer? Just one precaution; please use `floor()` carefully when you have negative number. `floor(-4.9)` will output `-5`. (a bit different from Excel function).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ultimately came up with

```
'N ' || floor ($y) || ' ' || round(($y - floor($y)) *60, 4) || 'W ' || abs(ceil($x)) || ' ' || round(abs($x -(ceil($x)))*60, 4)
```

| xcoord                       | ycoord                     | output

+---------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------

| -122.320783301429 | 47.6350075644759 | N 47 38.1005 W 122 19.247

| -122.320985539909 | 47.6348740787531 | N 47 38.0924 W 122 19.2591

Thanks for tip about floor.  Once I discovered ceil it all made sense.
Just wish I wasn't missing that trailing zero, but I can live with it.